# Button click not working in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Button don't work

```
class ContactList extends Component {


    addTrack() {
        console.log('addtrack');
    }

    render(){
        console.log('addtrackssss');

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ></input>
                    <button onclick={this.addTrack.bind(this)}>Add Track</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Where my mistake. Do all like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FwoKdOMaFI

Comment: bind your action in the constructor as  it is react best practice. @Reason: constructor bind will happen only once in the component life cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change onclick to onClick

Answer (score 3):

`onclick` should be `onClick`

Short answer, but its just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Handling events with React elements is very similar to handling events on DOM elements. But one of the difference is **React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase**.

```
//Regular Javascript:
<button onclick="doSomeThing()">
  Click me!
</button>

//React:
<button onClick={doSomeThing}>
  Click me!
</button>
```